# Datagridview on Windows 8.1 Tablet does not scroll to show all of last line

Tags: c#, scroll, datagridview, windows-8.1, tablet

I have a problem that I have been able to reproduce in about the simplist possible case--a single C# .net 4.0 WinForms form with a single data grid with about 100 hard-coded rows.

The data grid is fine on the windows desktop on a non-table.

But on 8.1 tablet's desktop, when I use a touch to scroll the datagrid to the bottom I run into problems.  Sometimes it takes a scroll or two, but pretty quickly it shows a problem where when the data grid's scrollbar thumb reaches the end of its movement, the grid does not completely show the last line.

Resizing the form and grid does not affect this.

Possibly related to this is a behavior where when you reach the end of the scrolling on the grid, the window itself moves with your finger for the last 1/2 inch or so.  i.e. as you move your finger up, when the scroll thumb hits the bottom, the grid stops scrolling (early) but the window moves up with your finger for just a bit.  Then as you release your finger the window pops back down that 1/2 inch or so.

At the same time that the window slides up at the end of the scroll, the hidden taskbar appears at the bottom of the screen.  It disappears as soon as the finger is lifted.

I am not doing anything fancy in this simple test.  Just a datagrid bound to 100 rows of ints.  I have the datagrid as readonly and in full row select.  I am not handling a single event for the form or grid.